# How to configure NServiceBus with RabbitMQ that has LDAP enabled

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus

Rabbit MQ set up in my organization uses LDAP for Authenticaton and Authorization.
How can I configure NServiceBus (or RabbitMQ) to use the credentials that the service is running under (- like integrated security for SQL Connections).

Rabbmit MQ Configuration

```
[
{rabbit,
   [{auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_ldap]}]},
  {rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap,
   [ {servers,               ["ad.xxxx.xxx"]},
     {dn_lookup_attribute,   "userPrincipalName"},
     {dn_lookup_base,        "OU=xxxx Users,DC=ad,DC=xxxx,DC=xxx"},
     {log,                   true},
     {group_lookup_base,     "OU=xxxx Users,DC=ad,DC=xxxx,DC=xxx"},
     {tag_queries,           [{administrator, {in_group, "CN=GRP_Name,OU=XXXX Users,DC=ad,DC=XXXX,DC=XXX"}},
                              {management, {in_group, in_group, "CN=GRP_Name,OU=XXXX Users,DC=ad,DC=XXXX,DC=XXX"}}]}
   ]
  }
].
```

NServiceBus Code:

```
var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("Receiver.Service");
            var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>();
            transport.UseConventionalRoutingTopology();
            transport.ConnectionString("host=rabbitmq.sb.xxxx.xxx");
```

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ's LDAP support requires that client applications pass a username and password. There is no equivalent to SQL's integrated security.

In your case, user's must have a `DN` whose value ends with `OU=xxxx Users,DC=ad,DC=xxxx,DC=xxx`. Your NServiceBus application will have to pass a username and password of an account with the expected `DN`.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ldap.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The unfortunate part is when the service account password changes - it will require update across the board for all services.